# Run Shell Script without Command line Arguments in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I am trying to run a Shell Script, but got stuck on an issue. I want to Run certain set of code when i supply arguments and remaining should run, if i dont pass any argument.
Part which i want to run with args:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ "$1" != "" ]]; do
case "$1" in
    -c )  cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cores
          ;;
    -d )  fdisk -l | grep Disk  | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' #fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | grep Disk | grep -v identifier
          ;;
    esac
 shift
done
```

and this part without any args

```
while [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; do
echo PART 2 $#
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cores
fdisk -l | grep Disk  | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' #fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | grep Disk | grep -v identifier
break
done
```

I believe issue is with the Loop condition, but i cant understand what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
  #
  # "$1" is not empty. This is the part which runs when one or more
  # arguments are supplied.
  #
  while [[ -n "$1" ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    -c) cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cores
        ;;
    -d) LC_ALL=C fdisk -l | grep Disk  | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
        #LC_ALL=C fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | grep Disk | grep -v identifier
        ;;
    esac
  shift
  done
  exit
fi
#
# "$1" is empty. The following code runs when no arguments are supplied.
#
echo PART 2 $#
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cores
LC_ALL=C fdisk -l | grep Disk | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}'
#LC_ALL=C fdisk -l 2> /dev/null | grep Disk | grep -v identifier
```

Note 1: Not tested.

Note 2: Whenever you feel a need to parse the output of a command looking for certain words or phrases it is a good idea to run the command in the default locale by prefixing it with `LC_ALL=C`. In this way you won't be surprised when in a French locale, for example, `fdisk` says `Disque`...

Comment: Thanks, for the reply... Can you please explain why my logic was failing?

Comment: Assuming that the posted code is the complete script then obviously after the first part `$#` is always zero, either because it was zero from the beginning or because you have `shift`ed all arguments, so the second part runs unconditionally.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.